# Passing an object as a parameter

Tags: java, function, object

I have a java code where i am trying to print a statement by passing an object of a class to a function . Following is the code :

```
import java.io.*;

class Abc
{

    public static void print(Object o)
    {
       o.name();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Vendor obj=new Vendor();
       print(obj);
    }
}

class Vendor
{
    public void name()
    {
       System.out.println("The name of the customer is chandeep");
    }

}
```

The error I am getting is, cannot find symbol name() in class Abc. I understand that's an appropriate error but how do i solve it!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `Object` class has no such method as `name()`, and you are trying to invoke it on a reference of type `Object`.

Just change the method signature to take `Vendor` reference as parameter: -

```
public static void print(Vendor vendor) {
     vendor.name();
}
```

Since your method `name()` is in `Vendor` class, and you are passing a reference of `Vendor`, so you don't need to use `Object` as formal parameter in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Because the parameter of the method `print()` is of type `Object` not of type `Vendor`. So its expecting any instance of type `Object`, which does not have a method `name()`. The actual instance might of course extend `Object` and have `name()` added to the list of methods, but the compiler cannot know that.

If you want the `print()` method to accept just `Vendor`, just change the parameter from `Object` to `Vendor`. If you want it to accept different objects, than you need a slightly more complex object oriented approach.

Comment: The OP did not indicate he was free to change the parameter type. If he is, then changing it is the right thing to do. If he's not , then your advice is useless, and he has to cast. Please think harder about other people's answers before you attack them as per below. Thanks. -1 for incomplete advice based on assumptions. -1 for attacking other posters who, actually, gave the correct answer.

Comment: And why can't he change it according to you? Class Abc is not implementing any interfaces or extending any Abstract classes that restrict it, so there was no restriction to not changing print() and the main() class was in the code he displayed, so put in context it is obvious that he is a beginner trying to learn OO concepts. I stated that if he wanted to accept different objects than he needs a more complex OO approach, which is NOT typecasting. As you can see from the answer he accepted, in fact it was the former. Typecasting is always considered a last resort, go learn some OOP first.

Comment: Hey thanks I am *quite* familiar with OOP. As to your rebuttal, no, the user says only that he "has" a class which is an ambiguous statement meaning nothing more than he is interacting with a class for some reason.. He may be the author, he may be a consumer. Nothing in his question indicates which it is. I therefore gave both answers. The point is, you have no business downgrading me since you were just factually, objectively wrong in your evaluation of my answer. If you're going to downgrade people, you owe it to them to be careful and accurate. You were neither.

Comment: You seem not to understand that software is written by independent teams who consume each others home-made classes. They don't have the option to alter the classes they are writing to (they "have" in the parlance of the OP). It's just as I said in my answer- if the parameter is generic, then you may have to cast if you can't rewrite it. BTW, downgrading other users should be a last resort, not a form of careless sport. It's people like you who spray their little sacks of bad temper over other users- thanks for the insult in your earlier post- that ruin online communities for other people.

Comment: My comment was not an insult, it was a technical critique. The purpose of this site is to answer questions in a way that can be useful to others in the same situation, thats why we recommend best practices, and if we're recommending something which is not in line we clearly say that its not preferred but a last resort. I did not 'downgrade' your answer, its just a -1, i.e. a vote against it and in line with the recommended policies of this site I also explained why. Its just an indicator to the OP and future readers that it is not the recommended answer. The OP could have chosen it anyway.

Comment: jbx said:Typecasting is always considered a last resort, go learn some OOP first" is an insult and you know it.

Comment: @JohnThompson It was not an insult. It was a response to you being upset that I voted down your response because it was teaching the wrong thing. I could interpret your previous message as an insult too with your same reasoning. Before thinking you can give an expert opinion about something make sure you are really an expert and check your facts first.

Answer (score -2):

IF you know o is a Vendor then cast it to type Vendor or rewrite the parameter type to just be Vendor instead of the generic Object in the method definition

Comment: Casting would be a bad idea.  Changing the parameter type would be a good idea.

Comment: Did the OP indicate he/she was free to change the parameter type of the method or did you just assume that? The answer is, you just assumed that. The method could be an API he/she is writing TO which has a deliberately generic parameter type i.e. equals(Object that) that he/she is not free to change. If you read what I wrote, you'd see I covered both cases and indicated a preference for changing parameter type if possible. You're assuming things the OP never said and giving bad advice based on that.